# Javascript Image manipulation Invert color

Tags: javascript, image-manipulation

I am trying to play with an image inside a webpage using javascript and it is being a pain.
I have no coding platform atm except my browser. It should invert the color I think but i'm not sure what is screwing up. What is wrong with my script?

```
<img src="C:\Documents and Settings\_username_\Desktop\rabbit.jpg" name="myimage" id="myimage">
<input type="button" value="Click Here" onClick="doSomething();">
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>

  function doSomething(){

    var imgd = myimage.getImageData(x, y, width, height); 
    var pix = imgd.data;  

    for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i < n; i += 4) {
       pix[i  ] = 255 - pix[i  ]; // red
       pix[i+1] = 255 - pix[i+1]; // green
       pix[i+2] = 255 - pix[i+2]; // blue
       // i+3 is alpha (the fourth element) 
    }  

    myimage.putImageData(imgd, x, y); 
  }
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would work on a `canvas` context, but you're working with an image. Create a `canvas` and copy the image's data into it and *then* invert the colors.

Comment: I'd add an example on JSFiddle of this, but JSFiddle doesn't host any images to test with and you can't copy an image from a remote host into a `canvas` and then read from it.

Comment: You can download image from any server. search for images in _Google Images_ for example.

Comment: @Andrew: Read more carefully. I said that if I got an image from a remote host and drew it into the `canvas`, you could no longer retrieve the pixel data, and thus, no longer invert the image.

Comment: @Andrew: And that's a bad example anyways, since Google proxies the thumbnails shown through their own servers.

Comment: Apparently my browser doesn't want to be compatable with canvas -.-'. Thanks for the help, I am gonna try this when I get home.

Comment: @Hazior: your browser is IE6-8 ? Why dont install other browser (for testing)?

Comment: @Andrew: Oh, I had forgotten about `data:` URIs.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MS Internet Explorer, the following code should work for you

```
<img src="xyz.jpg" onMouseover="this.style.filter='progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(invert=1)'" onMouseout="this.style.filter=''" />
```

Post IE 8 it the "**filter**" should be replaced by "**-ms-filter**"

Also a smarter way is mentioned at the sohtanaka site, which uses jquery and css to accomplish the required effect
http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/greyscale-hover-effect-w-css-jquery/

Hope this helps you :-)

Answer (score 2):

The [xolor library](https://github.com/fresheneesz/xolor) has an `inverse` function:

```
xolor("rgb(100,200,50").inverse().rgb // returns the inverse in rgb format
```

Its implemented like this, where it already parsed the red, green, and blue values which exist as properties on the xolor object:

```
this.inverse = function() {
    return xolor({
        r: this.r ^= 0xff,
        g: this.g ^= 0xff,
        b: this.b ^= 0xff
    })
}
```