# How to convert black pixel into white and white into black for Sobel filter Javascript

Tags: javascript, matrix, filter, pixel, sobel

I am working on sobel filer. For that I took the following code as the reference.
[Sobel Reference Code.](https://github.com/miguelmota/sobel/blob/master/README.md)

Using this code, I am getting sobel edges in white color and it's ranges and rest of the image in black color. I am trying to get the sobel edges in black color and it's ranges and rest of the image in white color. For that I tried to change the following loop but I didn't succeeded.

```
  for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
  for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    var pixelX = (
        (kernelX[0][0] * pixelAt(x - 1, y - 1)) +
        (kernelX[0][1] * pixelAt(x, y - 1)) +
        (kernelX[0][2] * pixelAt(x + 1, y - 1)) +
        (kernelX[1][0] * pixelAt(x - 1, y)) +
        (kernelX[1][1] * pixelAt(x, y)) +
        (kernelX[1][2] * pixelAt(x + 1, y)) +
        (kernelX[2][0] * pixelAt(x - 1, y + 1)) +
        (kernelX[2][1] * pixelAt(x, y + 1)) +
        (kernelX[2][2] * pixelAt(x + 1, y + 1))
    );

    var pixelY = (
      (kernelY[0][0] * pixelAt(x - 1, y - 1)) +
      (kernelY[0][1] * pixelAt(x, y - 1)) +
      (kernelY[0][2] * pixelAt(x + 1, y - 1)) +
      (kernelY[1][0] * pixelAt(x - 1, y)) +
      (kernelY[1][1] * pixelAt(x, y)) +
      (kernelY[1][2] * pixelAt(x + 1, y)) +
      (kernelY[2][0] * pixelAt(x - 1, y + 1)) +
      (kernelY[2][1] * pixelAt(x, y + 1)) +
      (kernelY[2][2] * pixelAt(x + 1, y + 1))
    );

    var magnitude = Math.sqrt((pixelX * pixelX) + (pixelY * pixelY))>>>0;
    sobelData.push(magnitude, magnitude, magnitude, 255);
  }
}
```

How can I get edges in black color and rest of the pixel in white color?

Comment: The code in the question here will work with canvas data. check out the algorithm and modify it to suit the variable names in your codebase. hope it helps [Javascript Image manipulation Invert color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606119/javascript-image-manipulation-invert-color)